# IntegrityError at /images/create/ NOT NULL constraint failed: images_image.users_like_id

Tags: python-3.x, django

I'm working on a project from the book 'Django3 by example'. I want to add an image from the URL which the user provided. But when I try to save the page it gives me this error:
IntegrityError at /images/create/
NOT NULL constraint failed: images_image.users_like_id.
I have tried the solutions other posted but it didn't help.

Here is my code:

models.py

```
from django.db import models
from django.conf import settings
from django.utils.text import slugify


class Image(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE, 
                            related_name='images_created')
    users_like = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE, 
                                  related_name='images_liked')
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=200, blank=True)
    url = models.URLField()
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='images/%Y/%m/%d/')
    description = models.TextField()
    created = models.DateField(auto_now_add=True, db_index=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if not self.slug:
            self.slug = slugify(self.title)
        super().save(*args, **kwargs)
```

views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required
from django.contrib import messages

from .forms import ImageCreateForm


@login_required
def image_create(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = ImageCreateForm(data=request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            cd = form.cleaned_data
            new_item = form.save(commit=False)
            new_item.user = request.user
            new_item.save()
        
            messages.success(request, 'Image added successfully')
            return redirect(new_item.get_absolute_url())
    else:
        form = ImageCreateForm(data=request.GET)

    context = {'section':'images', 'form':form}
    return render(request, 'images/image/create.html', context)
```

forms.py

```
from django import forms
from urllib import request
from django.core.files.base import ContentFile
from django.utils.text import slugify

from .models import Image



class ImageCreateForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Image
        fields = ('title', 'url', 'description')
        widgets = {
                'url': forms.HiddenInput,
        }


    def clean_url(self):
        url = self.cleaned_data['url']
        valid_extension = ['jpg', 'jpeg']
        extension = url.rsplit('.', 1)[1].lower()

        if extension not in valid_extension:
            raise forms.ValidationError('The given URL does not match valid image extension')
        return url      


    def save(self, force_insert=False, force_update=False, commit=True):
        image = super().save(commit=False)
        image_url = self.cleaned_data['url']
        name = slugify(image.title)
        extension = image_url.rsplit('.', 1)[1].lower()
        image_name = f'{image}.{extension}'

        response = request.urlopen(image_url)
        image.image.save(image_name, ContentFile(response.read()), save=False)

        if commit:
            image.save()
        return image
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm using a ForeignKey on users_like instead of ManyToManyField as a user might
like multiple images and each image can be liked by multiple users.